# How can I create layout for each device and each model in android studio and not using the layout-large folder or using the layout_sw320dp folder

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create a layout for each device and each model in Android Studio without using the `layout-large` folder or folders like the `layout_sw320dp` folder?

For example please see the following image.

I want create for all the phones and tablets a unique layout. I know there are the ways such as the `layout-large` folder and  or (in newer API levels) the `layout_sw320dp`, which I saw on the Android developer website.

But my question is how can I create a unique layout for each Android device and for each model?

[image: Select Hardware]

Comment: Why? This seems like a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a large image for all components that you use in layout and for all of objects in layout do scale it with phone screen by these codes:

```
DisplayMetric dm =new DisplayMetric();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int h= dm.heightPixels;
int w= dm.widthPixels;
h=h/10; // 10 is for example for 10% of display height
w=((w*20)/100); // 20%of display width
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w,h);
YourObject.setLayoutParams(params);
```

(Your object) can be everything such as button , image button, textview,...

Last line can copied and paste within number of your layout objects